# Soft and hardware for manipulating multi-million record data sets

Tags: bigdata

If starting from scratch, what hardware and software would be ideal and under \$5k or \$10k for manipulating a data set of 10 to 20 million records without slowing to the crashing point or taking several hours to complete? Manipulation, if it matters, means multivariate regression (simple OLS with less than a dozen variables), basic graphs, and tables.

Comment: Can you give us an idea of the size of the total data, in bytes? 10 million integers and 10 million book texts have very different storage requirements.

Comment: You also sayunder 5k or 10k ... is this USD? AUD ... different value ...

Comment: US$. The dataset is 35GB of voter registration records (public records).

Answer (score 1):

1. Use vowpal wabbit for building your regression or classification models. It'll train at the speed at which you can read your data

   2. Use pandas and dask for plotting graphs etc.
      You can use an AWS i2.8xlarge or equivalent machine which will cost you ~ USD 6k for an year